# taocp, sequential allocation questions

Tags: memory-management, taocp

i've run into few problems while working tacop 2.2.2 sequential allocations, repacking memory section at page 247.

the subject is there are n stacks sharing a common area locations L0 < L < LX, 
initially we set BASE[j] = TOP[j] = L0 for 1 <= j <= n

the goal is when overflow occurs while inserting or deleting elements with respect 
to stack i, how to repack memory. (making room for stack i by taking some away from 
tables that aren't yet filled).

a). find the smallest k for which i < k < n and TOP[k] < BASE[k+1], if any such k
exists. move things up one notch, 
   Set CONTENTS(L+1) -> CONTENTS(L), for TOP[k] >= L > BASE[i+1]
finally, 
   Set BASE[j] -> BASE[j] + 1, TOP[j] -> TOP[j] + 1, for i < j < k

here's my questions:

how do they find the stack that aren't yet to be filled? stack k? and why chose the smallest k?

Answer (score 2):

To find the stack that isn't yet filled, the basic idea used is the fact:

> Stack `k` is not full <==> `TOP[k] < BASE[k+1]`

The loop in the first step of the algorithm runs `k` from `i+1` to `n` to find the first `k` that satisfies this condition.

Also note that initially all space is given to the last, `n`th, stack by setting `BASE[n] = TOP[n] = L0` and `BASE[n+1]=LInfty`. So unless all "higher" stacks have been filled, we will find such a `k`.

Your second question (Why choose the smallest such `k`?) is more easily answered: The algorithm on Page 247 is *just one way of repacking* and a *simple* one at that. As Knuth mentions in the paragraph just above the text of the algorithm:

> Several ways to do the repacking suggest themselves; ...
>   We will start by giving the simplest of the methods, 
>   and will then consider some of the alternatives.

Later, Knuth describes a repacking approach that takes into account the earlier repacking, making the process somewhat adaptive.

Comment: umm...why not BASE[k+1] - TOP[k] > 1, since both BASE[k+1] and TOP[k] has a location, and if BASE[k+1] - TOP[k] = 1 , isn't that means BASE[k+1] is right after TOP[k]?

Comment: If I got you right, _no_: `BASE[k+1]` is unused in the `(k+1)`st stack, and is available for use by the `k`th stack (the last element of the `k`th stack can be stored at location `BASE[k+1]`).

So we need to check `BASE[k+1] - TOP[k] > 0` and _not_ `BASE[k+1] - TOP[k] > 1`.